# Chi-Square Computations

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $Y_1,Y_2,....Y_5$ i.i.d. $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Find the probability that $S^2/\sigma^2$ is between 0.20775 and 3.2075 where $S^2$ is the sample variance.

$P(4*0.20775 < 4*(S^2/\sigma^2$) < 4 * 3.2075) to find that this probability is equal to 0.95 which makes sense with a graph as the upper bound is 0.975 and lower bound is 0.025, however, I do not know how to represent the work in the middle to come up with this conclusion. Is there something like the Iota function to represent the in-between calculations?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121662/why-is-the-sampling-distribution-of-variance-a-chi-squared-distribution